# Run Plain C Project in Qt Creator

Tags: c, qt, gcc, qt-creator

I created a plain c project in qt creator using 
**File->New file or Project->Non Qt Projects->Plain C Project**

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

test.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.c
```

I build the project using Ctrl+B which was successful. But I am not able to run the project with Ctrl+R.
I earlier used to run the following command to compile and run c program

```
gcc main.c 
./a.out
```

But Now I am not able to get how to run c program in qt creator.
I am new to Qt Creator. Please Help

Comment: A way to trobuleshoot problems like this in QtC is generally, look at *Compile Output* and *Application Output* views, at the bottom of Qt Creator window (keyboard shortcuts *alt-4* and *alt-3* respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the run settings of your project correctly ?

Make sure to set them like this https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-run-settings.html

*edit: updated link for recent QtCreator version*

Seems like the working directory or executable path are missing.
Is there any output given  like "could not execute ./a.out : No such file or directory" ?

Comment: No there is not output

Comment: Thanks, After setting up the run setting my projects is running

Comment: You may want to check if QtCreator was adding/changing your test.pro . Maybe it added some Field you missed earlier.

Comment: This answer is little more than just a link (and to an ancient version of Qt Creator, no less). It should be expanded a bit to be self-contained, as answers at SO are supposed to be useful by their own content for future visitors.

Comment: Thanks hyde, updated the link tried to forumlate it more detailed.

Comment: FYI the link is dead.

Comment: @Addem thanks for the info, the archive still has it if you need it https://web.archive.org/web/20140810133019/https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.0/creator-run-settings.html