# Qt creator disable c++ and force plain c?

Tags: c, qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt creator for a plain c project. I managed to get it to use gcc to compile individual files, but it seems to be doing the final compiling using g++ (judging from what I saw in the Compile output window). Besides __cplusplus is defined for some reason, and I think that it messes up a library that I need to use. So how can I force Qt to do compiling and linking in plain c mode?

[image: screenshot of my qt creator with compile output window shown, that seems to indicate that qt uses gcc to compile individual file but g++ to actually link them]

I hope you can see it here the first grey line of compile output says its using gcc but the second line seems to indicate that it uses g++ for linking. I think that is the problem, so how can I change this setting?

In my actual project I am also using qmake.

Also here you can see that QMAKE_SPEC is set to linux-g++ can that be causing the issue?

[image: screen shot of qtcreator showing the options set for qmake under the "Build&Run" menu under tab "QT Versions"]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Plain C Project in Qt Creator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157339/run-plain-c-project-in-qt-creator)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have seen that post, but I think my problem is different. My code compiles and even runs, but the underlying library (which can operate in both c and c++ modes) currently runs in c++ mode because of the __cplusplus flag. I need to disable that flag. Its not the same as his Ctrl-R issue I think.

Comment: Try "QT -= gui" in your .pro file, to remove the Qt GUI library (which is written in C++).

Comment: we need more details about which type of project you are using(qmake/cmake/qbs/makefiles/whatever else). __cplusplus is defined for qtcreator itself for parsing of c++ code but it doesnt affect to build process

Comment: @TonyK I am using qmake so it should not be using any qt library at all.

Comment: @nib I edited the question to include more information.

Comment: Yep, qmake uses g++ to link binary. Ive created new `plain c' project from wizard in qtc(also had removed deployment.pri) and on my side everything looks ok. Check ldd output on your binary(mine depends on libc.so.6, linux-vdso.so.1 and ld). Also post errors from your c library